# Spring authorization and resource on same server

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to spring environment and i'm just learning oauth2.
Is there a way to make the authorization server also a resource server?
I am looking at this new project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server

Some steps or examples would be appreciated.
The first problem i encountered when trying to implement this so was that the provider for the resource server was not up already. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

To make Spring Authorization Server a Resource Server, I followed these steps:

1. Have your Spring Authorization Server working following the official documentacion: https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html
2. Add `.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)` to your second order SecurityFilterChain so that the code looks like:

```
  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
            authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        // ADD THIS LINE HERE
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
        // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
        // authorization server filter chain
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
```

Comment: Adding `.oauth2ResourceServer` to the *second* order `SecurityFilterChain` did the trick for me. In the official documentation it's added on the first order chain and it didn't work.

Comment: Note, that this configuration allows us to access all endpoints handled by this `SecurityFilterChain` both with the session cookie OR the JWT token. This can be mitigated in a few ways (like additional JWT checks in controllers). Alternatively, I've added an answer below that shows how to create a separate filter chain exclusively for the endpoints that have to be protected ONLY by the JWT.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenID Connect 1.0 UserInfo Endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) is an example of using both roles (Authorization Server, Resource Server) in the same server. This is due to the fact that the access token obtained from the authorization server is used directly to authenticate a request for the UserInfo endpoint. As an aside, I'm curious what your use case is for doing this.

Take a look at [this config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/068601b7c109261ef39e00a6db4985e286b149d4/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/config/annotation/web/configurers/OidcUserInfoTests.java#L459C15-L459C47) for the UserInfo endpoint tests, which demonstrates how to do this. The main thing that makes this work is exposing a [`JwtDecoder` as an `@Bean`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/3812c0e56e4786f685ac1216cd489e4690b6adf1/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/authorization/OidcUserInfoTests.java#L368) and omitting the `issuer-uri` property from your Spring Boot application's configuration.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I believe many would come here with the same motivation as me.
I have a Spring Boot back-end and an SPA front-end, and I want to secure the back-end with a JWT and Authorization Code Flow with PKCE.
It seems that after the deprecation of Spring Security OAuth, the only way to do it is by using the Spring Authorization Server. However, having a separate app just for the sake of switching from sessions to JWT feels like an overkill (I might be wrong though). So, combining the authorization and resource servers in one app seems like a solution.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3601262 I would say that regardless of it's (prolific) popularity as an approach, it is not a best practice to give access tokens to a SPA frontend which ultimately will store those tokens in browser storage (which is not secure). The recommended approach is to introduce a middleware service (usually a BFF) that uses sessions and acts as an OAuth2 Client for stateless backend services. This also hides the backend architecture from the frontend, which is another good practice.

Comment: thanks, what you said is reasonable, and I'll reevaluate my approach. 
However, it seems that even while using the middleware service, people still might want to merge the authorization and resource servers into one app just to reduce resource consumption and the infrastructure-related effort to support one more app.

Comment: @user3601262 my answer gives you an approach for that, does it not?

Comment: Reisenberg I'm still playing around with the solution, but looking at the /userinfo endpoint and related SecurityFilterChain surely helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Juan Cabello worked for me. Still, I wanted a more flexible configuration, so I decided to add a separate `SecurityFilterChain` that would be responsible solely for handling the endpoints that have to be protected by the access token. This way, we can have completely independent security configurations for the session-based and access-token-based endpoints.

I've made a sample project ([GitHub link](https://github.com/VKravchenk0/SO-Spring-authorization-server-demo)) that demonstrates this approach.
The readme contains the CLI commands to authorize with the Authorization Code Flow + PKCE, and commands to trigger the protected endpoints to ensure everything works as expected.

The main steps are the following:

1. Setup the server according to the [getting-started guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html)
2. Add a new filter chain in between the `authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain` and `defaultSecurityFilterChain`:

```
    // Manages authorization server endpoints such as /oauth2/**, /userinfo and others
    @Bean 
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        // config from the getting-started guide
    }
    
    // Manages endpoints that start with /api/
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain jwtFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/api/test/unprotected").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Ignoring the session cookie
                .sessionManagement(configurer ->
                        configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    
        return http.build();
    }
    
    // Manages everything else including the /login endpoint
    @Bean 
    @Order(3) // changed order from 2 to 3
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        // config from the getting-started guide
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.
you can find how I used in the authorization-server project on https://github.com/ythalorossy/project-library-spring

Answer (score 0):

Oauth is just a standardized flow to grant access to resources. There is no problem in implementing in the same server. But as the application scales out, this approach is not very good.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the obvious, but why would this approach be bad as the application scales out?

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a long time, I finally integrated the two on the same server, and made a simple page using angular as the front end.

Unfortunately, my English is not very good, so most of the words are in Chinese.

Here is the GitHub address:
https://github.com/qq253498229/spring-boot-oauth2-example

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [this demo](https://github.com/aker/oauth-authorization-server-sample) and the answer is http://127.0.0.1:8080/books .